# Running a Stored Procedure against all records in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm trying to create a SSIS package where I pull data from an Oracle source, insert into a destination table and run that data against a stored procedure that manipulates the data.

The stored procedure has the following variables:

```
@ShiftID Varchar (50),
@ProcedureID int,
@Registered int,
@Performed  int,
@Deferred  int,
@Collected  int,
@QNS int,
@Deleted int,
@Intent int,
@APH int,
@ResultError int output,
@ResultMessage varchar(1024) output
```

And the table I'd like to run the procedure against contain the following columns:

```
Shift_ID
ProcedureID
Registered
Performed
Deferred
Collected
QNS
Deleted
APH
```

Right now I have about 500 records in the table and I'd like to run this procedure against all records but I'm not sure how to go about this task.

How can I assign the variables to specific columns in the table and then have it loop or cursor through the entire table?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use after Insert trigger for that on the Staging table where you insert  rows from your ssis package .

Like this --

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerName] ON [dbo].[yourTableName]
AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @ShiftID VARCHAR(50)
    ,@ProcedureID INT
    ,@Registered INT
    ,@Performed INT
    ,@Deferred INT
    ,@Collected INT
    ,@QNS INT
    ,@Deleted INT
    ,@Intent INT
    ,@APH INT

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @ShiftID = ins.ShiftID
        ,@ProcedureID = ins.ProcedureID
        ,@Registered = ins.Registered
        ,@Performed = ins.Performed
        ,@Deferred = ins.Deferred
        ,@Collected = ins.Collected
        ,@Pincode = ins.Pincode
        ,@QNS = ins.QNS
        ,@Deleted = ins.Deleted
        ,@Intent = ins.Intent
        ,@APH = ins.APH
    FROM inserted ins

    -- TODO: Set parameter values here.
    EXECUTE [your Proc Name] @ShiftID
        ,@ProcedureID
        ,@Registered
        ,@Performed
        ,@Deferred
        ,@Collected
        ,@QNS
        ,@Deleted
        ,@Intent
        ,@APH
        -- Insert statements for trigger here
END
GO
```